# loops deeper in object by recursion

Tags: javascript, json, object, recursion

i tried to loop the object deeper because this object has tree, and very deep, to be able make it loop and get the data , i should try to recurion it, i got stuck here and the result is `undefined`

here is the data and the ouput is inside this:

```js
function operationEvaluator(operation) {
  Object.keys(operation).forEach(el => {
    if(typeof operation[el] === 'object'){
      return operationEvaluator(operation[el])
    }
    if(typeof operation[el] === 'number'){
       return operation.left + operationEvaluator(operation.op)
    } else {
      if(operation.op == '-'){
        return operation.left - operation.right.left
      } else if( operation.op == '*'){
        // console.log(operation.left*operation.right.left);
        return operation.left * operation.right.left
      } else if(operation.op == '+' ){
        return operation.left + operation.right.left
      } else if(operation.op == '/'  ){
        return operation.left / operation.right.left
      }
    }
  })
}


var op1 = {
  left: 5,
  op: '-',
  right: {
    left: 3,
    op: '*',
    right: {
      left: 8,
      op: '-',
      right: {
        left: 200,
        op: '/',
        right: 5,
      }
    }
  }
};

// prosses: 5 - (3 * (8 - (200 / 5)))
console.log(operationEvaluator(op1)); // 101

var op2 = {
  left: {
    left: 10,
    op: '*',
    right: {
      left: 2,
      op: '+',
      right: 1,
    },
  },
  op: '+',
  right: {
    left: 5,
    op: '*',
    right: {
      left: 1,
      op: '-',
      right: {
        left: 1,
        op: '+',
        right: 2,
      }
    }
  }
};

// prosses: ((10 * (2 + 1)) + (5 * (1 - (1 + 2)))
console.log(operationEvaluator(op2)); // 20
```

i tried to `console.log` each data in the last condition `else`, it shows the number of of `operation.left` and `operations.right.left`
but when i return it the result is undefined and nothing to show off

am i missed something ??
example on the else condition

IF operation equals `'*'`
 then i console.log the operation.left and operation.right.left
it shows the numbers and i tried to multiply it by console.log, it shows the result,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote your code slightly, using a `switch` statement for the operators :

```js
const operationEvaluator = operation => {

  let left = (typeof operation.left === "number") ? operation.left : operationEvaluator(operation.left),
    right = (typeof operation.right === "number") ? operation.right : operationEvaluator(operation.right);

  switch (operation.op) {
    case "*":
      return left * right
    case "/":
      return left / right
    case "+":
      return left + right
    case "-":
      return left - right
  }
}

var op1 = { left: 5, op: '-', right: { left: 3, op: '*', right: { left: 8, op: '-', right: { left: 200, op: '/', right: 5 } } } },
op2 = { left: { left: 10, op: '*', right: { left: 2, op: '+', right: 1, }, }, op: '+', right: { left: 5, op: '*', right: { left: 1, op: '-', right: { left: 1, op: '+', right: 2 } } } };


console.log(operationEvaluator(op1))
console.log(operationEvaluator(op2))
```

Comment: Well, as much as I am the first fan of Nina's code elegance, I have to admit that object destructuring isn't necessary for this kind of little recursion, and I also think this is much simpler.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) in the parts `left`, `right` and `op` and a helper object for the operators and their functions.

Then check for `left` and `right` operands if they are object, then make a recursive call to the function with this object or just hand over the value.

```js
function operationEvaluator({ left, op, right }) {
    const
        operators = {
            '+': (a, b) => a + b,
            '-': (a, b) => a - b,
            '*': (a, b) => a * b,
            '/': (a, b) => a / b
        },
        getOperand = o => typeof o === 'object'
            ? operationEvaluator(o)
            : o;

    return operators[op](getOperand(left), getOperand(right));
}

var op1 = { left: 5, op: '-', right: { left: 3, op: '*', right: { left: 8, op: '-', right: { left: 200, op: '/', right: 5 } } } },
    op2 = { left: { left: 10, op: '*', right: { left: 2, op: '+', right: 1, }, }, op: '+', right: { left: 5, op: '*', right: { left: 1, op: '-', right: { left: 1, op: '+', right: 2 } } } };

// prosses: 5 - (3 * (8 - (200 / 5)))
console.log(operationEvaluator(op1)); // 101
// prosses: ((10 * (2 + 1)) + (5 * (1 - (1 + 2)))
console.log(operationEvaluator(op2)); // 20
```

Comment: I was thinking, "I would be curious to see Nina's answer on this question" and... here you are :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code fixed below:

```js
function operationEvaluator(operation) {
    let computedRightTerm;
    let computedLeftTerm;
    if(typeof operation.right === 'number') {
      computedRightTerm = operation.right;
    }
    else {
      computedRightTerm = operationEvaluator(operation.right);
    }
    if(typeof operation.left=== 'number') {
      computedLeftTerm= operation.left;
    }
    else {
      computedLeftTerm= operationEvaluator(operation.left);
    }
    if(operation.op == '-'){
      return computedLeftTerm - computedRightTerm;
    } else if( operation.op == '*'){
      // console.log(operation.left*operation.right.left);
      return computedLeftTerm * computedRightTerm;
    } else if(operation.op == '+' ){
      return computedLeftTerm + computedRightTerm;
    } else if(operation.op == '/'  ){
      return computedLeftTerm / computedRightTerm;
    }
}


var op1 = {
  left: 5,
  op: '-',
  right: {
    left: 3,
    op: '*',
    right: {
      left: 8,
      op: '-',
      right: {
        left: 200,
        op: '/',
        right: 5,
      }
    }
  }
};

// prosses: 5 - (3 * (8 - (200 / 5)))
console.log(operationEvaluator(op1)); // 101

var op2 = {
  left: {
    left: 10,
    op: '*',
    right: {
      left: 2,
      op: '+',
      right: 1,
    },
  },
  op: '+',
  right: {
    left: 5,
    op: '*',
    right: {
      left: 1,
      op: '-',
      right: {
        left: 1,
        op: '+',
        right: 2,
      }
    }
  }
};

// prosses: ((10 * (2 + 1)) + (5 * (1 - (1 + 2)))
console.log(operationEvaluator(op2)); // 20
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's make it as simple as possible. `eval` takes an expression `e` -

```
const eval = e =>
  // if the expression is an object ...
  Object (e) === e
    // apply the operator to the evaluated operands ...
    ? apply (e.op, eval (e.left), eval (e.right))
    // otherwise the expression is already a primitive
    : e
```

`apply` is simple too -

```
const env =
  { '+': (a, b) => a + b
  , '-': (a, b) => a - b
  , '*': (a, b) => a * b
  , '/': (a, b) => a / b
  }

const apply = (f, ...args) =>
{ if (env[f] === undefined)
    throw Error (`unknown operator: ${f}`)
  else
    return env[f] (...args)
}
```

Try and see -

```
eval (op1)
// 101

eval (op2)
// 20

eval ({ left: 10, op: '^', right: 2 })
// unknown operator: ^
```

Expand the snippet below to verify the results in your own browser -

```js
const env =
  { '+': (a, b) => a + b
  , '-': (a, b) => a - b
  , '*': (a, b) => a * b
  , '/': (a, b) => a / b
  }

const eval = e =>
  Object (e) === e
    ? apply (e.op, eval (e.left), eval (e.right))
    : e
  
const apply = (f, ...args) =>
{ if (env[f] === undefined)
    throw Error (`unknown operator: ${f}`)
  else
    return env[f] (...args)
}

const op1 =
  { left: 5, op: '-', right: { left: 3, op: '*', right: { left: 8, op: '-', right: { left: 200, op: '/', right: 5 } } } }

const op2 =
  { left: { left: 10, op: '*', right: { left: 2, op: '+', right: 1, }, }, op: '+', right: { left: 5, op: '*', right: { left: 1, op: '-', right: { left: 1, op: '+', right: 2 } } } }

console .log
  ( eval (op1) // 101
  , eval (op2) // 20
  )
```